# How to preview image before upload with ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs

This is code snippet.

When user select a file by clicking on Change Image button, file gets selected and name is displayed in text box.

```
<img src="" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75><br><br>

<input type="text" ng-model="b.files[0].name" data-ng-hide="!uploadMode" readonly="readonly">

<button ngf-select ng-model="b.files" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="uploadMode=1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Change Image
</button>
```

I also want to display the image of selected file to preview to user, before actual upload.

Can please any one help me, what changes i need to do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/tree/master/examples/image-preview) (`ngThumb` directive). Basically, it's all about using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API and listening to the appropriate events.